# Broken tikz chains

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I tried to use the tikz chains feature today, and all was good for a few hours, but now I get an error every time I try to use chains

```
./test.tex:7: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/nonterminal' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [    \node [nonterminal]]
./test.tex:8: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/terminal' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [    \node [terminal]]
./test.tex:9: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/terminal' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [    \node [terminal]]
./test.tex:10: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/terminal' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [    \node [terminal]]
```

And here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% Add packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=5mm, every node/.style={on chain,join}, every join/.style={->}]
    \node [nonterminal]  {unsigned integer};
    \node [terminal]     {.};
    \node [terminal]     {digit};
    \node [terminal]     {E};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any good ideas on how to repair the chain?

Comment: Well, you don’t have a definition for the `terminal` nor the `nonterminal` style. The example (or another one) in the [PGf manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), p. 61, defines them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Qrrbrbirlbel (name chosen to be difficult to write? :p) said, you haven't defined your `terminal` and `nonterminal` style. The pgfkeys errors are hinting about this as they complain that `tikz/nonterminal`and `tikz/terminal`are unknown. Some times, `TikZ` recognise if you try to use keys from a `tikzlibrary` you should have loaded with `usetikzlibrary`, and will say so.

In the `TIKZandPGF-manual` the styles are set with `tikzset`, but are given in the `tikzpicture` options (`[]`) in the examples on page 60 and 61. You'll also need to load the `shapes.misc` library to be able to produce the `rounded rectangle`. The code is given below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
    nonterminal/.style={
      rectangle,
      minimum size=6mm,
      very thick,
      draw=red!50!black!50,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=red!50!black!20,
      font=\itshape},
    terminal/.style={
      rounded rectangle,
      minimum size=6mm,
      very thick,draw=black!50,
      top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
      font=\ttfamily}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=5mm, every node/.style={on chain,join}, every join/.style={->}]
    \node [nonterminal]  {unsigned integer};
    \node [terminal]     {.};
    \node [terminal]     {digit};
    \node [terminal]     {E};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]